# Definite Parity of Solutions to a Schrödinger Equation with 3 dimensional central potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

It says that Parity of a 3 dimensional central potential is given by $$ P\psi=(-1)^l\psi $$

Can anyone please explain me why it is true?

Answer (score 0):

For a central potential, the Schrödinger equation can be split in its radial and angular components (separation of variables). The angular component is essentially the angular part of the Laplacian, whose eigenvalue problem is well-known. The eigenstates of the Laplacian are the spherical harmonics $Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$, which satisfy the parity condition in the question.

It is most easily understood by seeing the expression of the spherical harmonics in terms of the Cartesian coordinates. Put simply, they are (powers of $r$ aside) combinations of monomials of order $l$. If one changes the coordinates from $(x,y,z)$ to $(-x, -y, -z)$, a global $(-1)^l$ appears.